# Get name of component from ReactElement.type.name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with Typescript and it is necessary to get the name of functional component which I found can be accessed inside of 'type' property of component `component.type.name`. I gave the component a type of ReactElement, because I see on console, that

> $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)

But I'm getting an error from Typescript:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | JSXElementConstructor'. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

That's because of the interface of ReactElement:

```
interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
    type: T;
    props: P;
    key: Key | null;
}
```

Is there any way to change the type of `type` to function, because I see it as a function from my console?

> type: (props) => {…}

And as far as any function has a `name` property, to access this `name` property?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using property `displayName` to find out a component's name: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname.

Comment: Thank you! I think it is only for class components nad can only be used inside the component. I really need something, that can be used outside the component and not in parent